# KdB+ - HTML5 websocket deserializer not working for Long data type

Tags: html, websocket, kdb

I am using the deserializer from https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/c.js for interfacing HTML 5 websocket to KdB+ backend. I am facing issues while sending null values of type j(long) from the backend. The deserializer for some reason maps it to 64-bit integer min value i.e., -9223372036854775808. Non-null values are getting deserialized properly though. And this is happening only for null long values , null int and float are deserilized properly.

Comment: All the language APIs for KDB+ map null to `NumberType.MIN_VALUE`. That is expected. I haven't looked at the JS integration before, but I'm surprised null int/float work ok - I'd expect them to do the same. Does JS even support 64bit int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly pointed out in the comment by user2393012, the serializer for KdB+ maps 0N(null) to the min value of the data type. Hence a null value of Long type gets serialized to -9223372036854775808.

The deserializer is handling this integer min correctly for 16 bit and 32 bit values as illustrated in the below code.

```
function rInt16(){rNUInt8(2);var h=hb[0];return h==-32768?NaN:h==-32767?-Infinity:h==32767?Infinity:h;}
function rInt32(){rNUInt8(4);var i=ib[0];return i==-2147483648?NaN:i==-2147483647?-Infinity:i==2147483647?Infinity:i;}
```

However the deserializer for 64bit integer doesn't perform any checks for the min value as seen below

```
function rInt64(){rNUInt8(8);var x=ib[1],y=ib[0];return x*j2p32+(y>=0?y:j2p32+y);}// closest number to 64 bit int...
```

This is because javascript can handle only integers upto +/- 2^53 safely. See this [link](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html#_representing_integers_as_floating_point_numbers) for more on JS integers.

I have come around this short coming by making a compromise that my application will handle only values upto +/- 2^53 and anything outside this range will be returned as NaN by the deserializer as shown below.

```
function rInt64(){
    rNUInt8(8);
    var x=ib[1],y=ib[0];
    var ret = x*j2p32+(y>=0?y:j2p32+y);
    if(ret > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || ret < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)
        return NaN;
    return ret;
}
```

If your application still needs to work on the full range of 64 bit integers I would suggest that you cast the integer to String before KdB+ sends the data and use some Big Int libraries available in JS to contruct the integer back again from the String.